# How to view data from excel in flex app?

Tags: java, apache-flex, excel, user-interface, blazeds

I have a flex-application deployed on tomcat with blazeds. User constantly selects ranges excel-document. Now, a user enters a cell addresses in text fields (for example, C1: C20). But it is very inconvenient! How to display excel-data as a table in my application? I think, I can parse excel-document using Apach POI and transmit these data to the Flex-application. But there are other ways?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, Adobe Flex doesn't provide direct way to bring the Microsoft Excel data into a Flex component and if you try to implement Excel system with DataGrid component, you will found a great pain.

I googled around and found a component that might solve your problem, [flexuscalculus](http://currentlabel.co.uk/flexuscalculus/) or [Flex spreadsheet](http://code.google.com/p/flexspreadsheet/).

Hope they can help you. :)

Comment: Thanks. You have helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use a java library for example http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/ to parse the excel file in the server side and then return a collection of objects to the flex client in order to render the data into a datagrid for example...